# Webapp2 Google App Engine Firebase import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, webapp2

I want to use Firebase in my app engine project. I have followed the instructions mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) for using the third party libraries. Whenever I try to import Firebase:

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('ttps://myapp-c1367.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/users', None)
print result
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\simpletestapp - MVC\controllers\Handlers.py", line 24, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\simpletestapp - MVC\controllers\Login.py", line 45, in get
    from firebase import firebase
  File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\simpletestapp - MVC\lib\firebase\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .async import process_pool
  File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\simpletestapp - MVC\lib\firebase\async.py", line 1, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

Please help. Where am I doing a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the `firebase` package importing python's `multiprocessing` package, which is in turn trying to import the `subprocess` package.

The Appengine standard runtime environment does not allow `subprocess` to be imported, as background processes are not allowed on Appengine.

If you want to use Firebase with your app you will have you communicate with it using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/), or move your project to a [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) or a custom runtime on Compute Engine.